# Load Dask dataframe from remote web server (HTTPS) with custom headers

Tags: python, jwt, dask

I would like to load some Dask data from a remote server that exposes the storage via HTTPS. This requires an OIDC JSON web token passed as one of the request headers.

From reading the documentation (https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/how-to/connect-to-remote-data.html), it's not clear to me that the `storage_options` for `read_csv` can take custom headers?

Can someone confirm whether, and how, this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this works. The documentation for the filesystem is [here](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fsspec.implementations.http.HTTPFileSystem) sand it specifies that any kwargs aside from the ones explicitl;y listed get passed on to requests/aiohttp. So you will want something like:

```
dd.read_csv(url, storage_options={"headers": {...}})
```